# Azure App wont start

Tags: silverlight, azure, role

every time i try starting my azure application. I try building it and it says it has all successful build attempts but i am getting an error that says: "Windows Azure Tools: Start role failed for one or more roles
" I cannt see why i am getting this error, since i followed every step as stated in the tutorial videos. please help. I am using visual studio 2010 and the new tools that were created for it since this week.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue.  Hitting f5 on an azure project with an https endpoint defined woudl produce the error dialog "Windows Azure Tools: Start role failed for one or more roles".

On the system where this repro'd i'd get an eventlog | system error entry with the message "A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10001."

I tried switching to the azure sdk provided 127.0.0.1 cert for my https endpoint cert to see if it would create the same issue as when using my own.  Before using it I tried to check its private key permissions to ensure that “Network Service” had read permissions and it thre an error when I tried to open the “Manage Private Keys…” UI.

I deleted the 127.0.0.1 cert from the store and left it for azure sdk to redeploy it and after that I could successfully f5 on https endpoint enabled azure project using that cert or my own.

It would appear that cert’s private key permissions area got messed up during my 1.3 -> 1.4 -> 1.4.1 refresh upgrade processing and the f5 error dialog “Windows Azure Tools: Start role failed for one or more roles” was the signature of this issue.

This is likely some documented issue that can arise that i didn't read.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

In my case, it was because the path to my VS solution was too long or because it contained spaces. I used the default paths, which were something like C:\Users\My Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProjectName. When I instead created the project under C:\Test, the problem went away.